# One-to-one with two independent tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have two tables: `Indivdiual` and `Instructor`.  If an `Instructor` is an `Individaul` (that we track), I want to link their `Instructor` record to their `Individual` record.  An `Individual` may or not be an `Instructor` and an `Instructor` may or may not be an `Individual`.

```
public Instructor
{
    public int? IndividualId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IndividualId")]
    public virtual Individual Individual { get; set; }
}

public Individual
{
    public virtual Instructor Instructor { get; set; }
}
```

I am receiving the error `Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'ILETSB.PTB.Domain.Entities.Instructor' and 'ILETSB.PTB.Domain.Entities.Individual'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This doesn't look like it has anything to do with ASP.NET MVC, so I've removed those tags. You may want to add some tags that are more appropriate. It looks like you're using Entity Framework, so perhaps tags to that effect. It may also be relevant to state which framework/library you are using in the question itself.

Comment: Why would an instructor not be an individual?

Comment: Individuals are Law Enforcement Officers and you don't have to be a Law Enforcement Officer to be an instructor (and vice versa).  I wanted to track to see how many Law Enforcement Officers are also instructors, but maybe I just put the IndividualId in the Instructor table but don't have a relationship?

Answer (score 0):

If an instructor may, or may not be an officer, and an officer may or may not be an instructor, then there is no "Is a" relationship, just two separate entities that might be associated.

```
public class Individual 
{
    [Key]
    public int IndividualId { get; set; }
}

public class Instructor
{
    [Key]
    public int InstructorId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Individual))]
    public int? IndividualId { get; set; }
    public Individual? Individual { get; set; }
}
```

With EF 6 I believe you will need to treat this as a one-sided one-to-many, though I will check and revise if it can handle it as a one to one with a FK.  (Does work with EF Core with `.HasOne(x=> x.Individual).WithOne())`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Instructor>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.Individual)
    .WithMany();
```

Provided you aren't using a soft-delete system you can maintain a null-able Unique Constraint on Instructor.IndividualId to enforce the one-to-one.